# JSON_MODIFY Remove Array Objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you remove an object from a `VARCHAR(MAX)` JSON array?

## Setup

```
DECLARE @Json VARCHAR(MAX) =
JSON_QUERY('[{"u":"user1","i":"item1"},{"u":"user2","i":"item2"}]')

SELECT @Json

DECLARE @NewJson VARCHAR(MAX) =
JSON_QUERY('{"u":"user3","i":"item3"}')

SELECT @NewJson
```

Result

```
[{"u":"user1","i":"item1"},{"u":"user2","i":"item2"}]

{"u":"user3","i":"item3"}
```

## Append `@NewJson` to `@Json`

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@Json, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(@NewJson))
```

Result

```
[{"u":"user1","i":"item1"},{"u":"user2","i":"item2"},{"u":"user3","i":"item3"}]
```

All good.

## Remove Index `0` from `@Json`

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@Json, '$[0]', NULL)
```

Result

```
[null,{"u":"user2","i":"item2"}]
```

I don't want index `0` to be null. I want it removed.

I can't find anything in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql) that state how to remove an object from an array.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with json but, since its a string you could do this;

```
SET @Json = JSON_MODIFY(@Json, '$[0]', NULL);
SET @Json = STUFF(@Json, CHARINDEX ('null,', 5, '');
```

Note That I can't test this code at the moment.

Comment: Pretty hacky, but I guess it works if TSQL doesn't provide a native function for this.